# mostrar la suma total y mostrarla en variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla de clasificación de pilotos [similar a la de este sitio web](http://www.caranddriver.es/formula-1/clasificacion/2017):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el único problema que tengo que no me muestra la suma total de puntos bien, osea no me calcula la suma bien. Lo demás está bien el único problema que tengo es eso.

Éste es mi código con la consulta:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT
clasificacion_pilotos.id,
clasificacion_pilotos.fk_pilotos,
clasificacion_pilotos.au,
clasificacion_pilotos.ch,
clasificacion_pilotos.ba,
clasificacion_pilotos.ru,
clasificacion_pilotos.es,
clasificacion_pilotos.mo,
clasificacion_pilotos.ca,
clasificacion_pilotos.az,
clasificacion_pilotos.at,
clasificacion_pilotos.gb,
clasificacion_pilotos.hu,
clasificacion_pilotos.be,
clasificacion_pilotos.it,
clasificacion_pilotos.sg,
clasificacion_pilotos.ma,
clasificacion_pilotos.ja,
clasificacion_pilotos.usa,
clasificacion_pilotos.me,
clasificacion_pilotos.br,
clasificacion_pilotos.ab,
pilotos.nombresyapellidos FROM clasificacion_pilotos INNER JOIN pilotos ON 
clasificacion_pilotos.fk_pilotos=pilotos.id
WHERE clasificacion_pilotos.fk_pilotos=pilotos.id ORDER BY id";
$consulta = $DB_con->prepare($sql);
$consulta->execute();
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
$i=1;
echo "<table class='striped responsive-table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Pos.</th>
          <th>Piloto</th>
          <th>Tot.</th>
          <th>AU</th>
          <th>CH</th>
          <th>BA</th>
          <th>RU</th>
          <th>ES</th>
          <th>MO</th>
          <th>CA</th>
          <th>AZ</th>
          <th>AT</th>
          <th>GB</th>
          <th>HU</th>
          <th>BE</th>
          <th>IT</th>
          <th>SG</th>
          <th>MA</th>
          <th>JA</th>
          <th>USA</th>
          <th>ME</th>
          <th>BR</th>
          <th>AB</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>";
 while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


  $total = array_reduce(array_keys($linea), function($v, $k) use($linea) {
      if ($k !== 'linea') {
        return $v += $linea[$k];


    }
   });
   ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['nombresyapellidos']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $total;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['au']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ch']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ba']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ru']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['es']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['mo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ca']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['az']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['at']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['gb']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['hu']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['be']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['it']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['sg']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ma']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ja']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['usa']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['me']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['br']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $linea['ab']; ?></td>
      </tr>
   <?php
  $i++;
  }
  }else
  echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
 <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>¡ Advertencia: 
 No se ha encontrado ningún registro !</h5>
</div>";
?>
</table>
```

¿Qué es lo que está fallando? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que la suma se calcule bien?

Comment: ¿A qué suma total te refieres? La suma de puntos de cada piloto parece hacerse bien, en la columna `Tot`. Lo mismo la suma de puntos de equipos, excepto `Haas` que tiene un total de 4 pero no aparece nada en las columnas de la derecha. No sé si te refieres a eso, pues no lo dices con claridad. Si ese es el problema, no muestras en la pregunta la consulta de equipos. ¿O te refieres a una suma general de todos los puntos? Por otra parte, el `WHERE` sobra en tu consulta: `INNER JOIN pilotos ON 
clasificacion_pilotos.fk_pilotos=pilotos.id
WHERE clasificacion_pilotos.fk_pilotos=pilotos.id`.

Comment: la pagina que puse es un ejemplo de lo que estoy haciendo, lo que quiero mostrar es la suma total de cada piloto en la mía lo da pero da el total mal en el ejemplo que puse la suma total de los dos pilotos primeros da 43 en la  mía da 45

Comment: He votado para cierre. Es un problema que no se puede reproducir, la pregunta no era clara y el OP encontró una solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**listo ya lo resolví hay que cambiar esto**

```
 $total = array_reduce(array_keys($linea), function($v, $k) use($linea) {
  if ($k !== 'linea') {
    return $v += $linea[$k];


}
});
```

**por esto**

```
 $total = $linea["au"] + $linea["ch"] + $linea["ba"] + $linea["ru"] + $linea["es"] + $linea["mo"] + $linea["ca"] + 
       $linea["az"] + $linea["at"] + $linea["gb"] + $linea["hu"] + $linea["be"] + $linea["it"] + $linea["sg"] +  
       $linea["ma"] + $linea["ja"] + $linea["usa"] + $linea["me"] + $linea["br"] + $linea["ab"];
```

Comment: Me alegro. Pero para la próxima plantea el problema cómo se presenta en la realidad, tratando de indicar donde falla. Saludos.